# Real Valued Function on the real line

Tags: real-analysis, functions, metric-spaces

I don't know how to prove this:
It's the Exercise 3.4.7 of Avner Friedman's Foundations of Modern Analysis

Let $f(x)$ be a real-valued function on the real line. Prove that there is a nonempty interval $(a,b)$ and a positive numer $c$ such that for any $x \in (a,b)$ there is a sequence {$ x_n $} such that $x_n$ $\rightarrow x$ and
 |$f(x_n)$| $\leq c$

Comment: Is $f$ assumed to be continuous?

Answer (score 3):

This is not true. Let's say that $x$ is $f$-finite if there exists a sequence $(x_n)$ converging to $x$ such that $f(x_n)$ stays bounded. I can actually define a function $f$ such that every rational $x$ is *not* $f$-finite. For this, let $(q_n)$ be an enumeration of $\mathbb Q$. Let's start with $q_1$ and choose a sequence of irrationals $(x_n^{(1)})$ that converges to $q_1$. Define $f(x_n^{(1)}) = n$. Then obviously $q_1$ is not $f$-finite. Now, consider $q_2$. We can find an irrational sequence $(x_n^{(2)})$ which is disjoint to $(x_n^{(1)})$ and converges to $q_2$. Set $f((x_n^{(2)}) = n$. Next, we find an irrational sequence that is disjoint to $(x_n^{(1)})$ and $(x_n^{(2)})$ which converges to $q_3$. Set $f(x_n^{(2)}) = n$. And so on. For the points that have not been touched set $f(x) = 0$.

So, any rational $x$ is not $f$-finite. So, whatever open interval $(a,b)$ you choose there will be a rational $x$ in it. Thus, in any open interval there is a point that is not $f$-finite.